# How to serialize field from intermediate model into the main model of a many to many through relationship?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using django 2 with Django Rest Framework and I have the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    description = models.TextField()


class ProductStorageCenter(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    storage_center_id = models.ForeignKey(StorageCenter)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()


class StorageCenter(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through="ProductStorageCenter")
```

I would like to know which products I have in each StorageCenter and also the quantity of a product available in that StorageCenter.
How could show a list of StorageCenters containing all its Products and the quantity of each Product for that StorageCenter?

The JSON return would be like this:

```
[
    {   "id": 1,
        "name": "My Storage Center",
        "city": 1,
        "products": [
            {   
                "id": 1,
                "name": "My Product 1",
                "description": "My Product Description 1",
                "quantity": 200            
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "My Product 2",
                "description": "My Product Description 2",
                "quantity": 500            
            }
        ]    
    },    
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "My Storage Center 2,
        "city": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "My Product 1",
                "description": "My Product Description 1",
                "quantity": 350            
            }
        ]    
    }
]
```

EDIT:

Now I can get the JSON above but I don't think this is the best solution. In My StorageCenterSerializer I get the products of that StorageCenter with a function instead of just use ProductSerializer. Then I loop the Product queryset and later retrive the quantity for that Product in that StorageCenter.

Here are my serializers now:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    quantity = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'quantity')


class StorageCenterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = StorageCenter
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'city', 'products')


    def get_products(self, obj):
        products = Product.objects.filter(productstoragecenter__storage_center_id = obj.id)

        for product in products:

            psc = ProductStorageCenter.objects.get(storage_center_id = obj.id, product_id = product.id)
            product.quantity = psc.quantity

        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)

        return serializer.data
```

Comment: Please add your `serializer.py` file

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good manners here require you to also show which efforts you have already attempted to solve the problem yourself. See [ask] question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) with `many=True`.

You didn't post your serializers, so here's the example from DRF's documentation:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

When you'll serialize Album. you'll get the nested tracks:

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

Comment: The serializer you posted is exactly what I have here. Show every Product of each StorageCenter is no problem. The trick is to get the field "quantity" and put it inside the products. The field "quantity" is in the intermediate model between Product and StorageCenter since the product can have different "quantity" for the StorageCenters it is in. I just can't think how to get the "quantity" and put together with the other product data.

Comment: ProductStorage has ManyToOne relationship to Product, so many of those can be for a specific product. Which one of those are you going to use for quantity?

Comment: I am going to use the quantity of the product in the parent StorageCenter in the json structure. In the JSON I show all StorageCenters, each StorageCenter has a list of Product, so the quantity of each product in the list will have to be the one related to that StorageCenter.

Comment: In that case I would've filtered on the through table (with `select_related()` on `product`) and use a custom serializer to produce the result.

Answer (score 0):

As for Your Question, you are missing the City Model due to which i could not attend to your code directly but i can refer you an example which does the thing you need,

NOTE: As a Software Engineer, I love to use Architectures and I have deeply worked on Layered Approach for Development so I am gonna be Answering it with Respect to Tiers.

```
serializer = SerializerNameGoesHere(AllFilteredObjectsfromModel, many=True)
```

would serializer m2m.
Here's an Example in Layered Approach!

As i understood the Issue, Here's the Solution

models.py

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_name = models.CharField(max_length = 

class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    fk_member_id = models.ForeignKey('Member', models.DO_NOTHING, 
                             db_column='fk_member_id', blank=True, null=True)

class Membership(models.Model):
    membershipid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fk_group_id = models.ForeignKey('Group', models.DO_NOTHING, 
                             db_column='fk_member_id', blank=True, null=True)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

serializers.py

```
import serializer

class AllSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    group_id = serializer.IntegerField()
    group_name = serializer.CharField(max_length = 20)
    join_date = serializer.DateTimeField()
```

CustomModels.py

```
imports...

    class AllDataModel():
        group_id = ""
        group_name = ""
        join_date = ""
```

BusinessLogic.py

```
imports ....
class getdata(memberid):
    alldataDict = {}
    dto = []
    Member = models.Members.objects.get(member_id=memberid) #or use filter for Name
    alldataDict["MemberId"] = Member.member_id
    alldataDict["MemberName"] = Member.member_name
    Groups = models.Group.objects.filter(fk_member_id=Member)
    for item in Groups:
        Custommodel = CustomModels.AllDataModel()
        Custommodel.group_id = item.group_id
        Custommodel.group_name = item.group_name
        Membership = models.Membership.objects.get(fk_group_id=item.group_id)
        Custommodel.join_date = Membership.join_date
        dto.append(Custommodel)
    serializer = AllSerializer(dto,many=True)
    alldataDict.update(serializer.data)
    return alldataDict
```

now what you can do is:

```
#Member = models.Members.objects.get(member_id=memberid)
Member = models.Members.objects.filter(member_id=memberid)
#And then Loop over it
for item in Member:
   #The Rest of the code would go here!
```

Comment: I always want the Customized Control over my Application to follow the rule "Close for Modification, Open for Extention" so that is why i usually avoid the direct stuff rather go custom for easy maintenance at later stages!
You Would need to Study Custom Models in a Little Order, as it is the core part of the Tier Archietecture!

Comment: Very Breifly Explained!